# Can’t find OpenVPN config file in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I have a problem locating OpenVPN config files on both Ubuntu 20.04 and 19.10. It is not in any usual locations

I searched through entire disk via this but command but not hits:

```
find / -name
```

I was looking for `.ovpn`, `.conf`, `.config`, I found nothing.

I am using `nm-openvpn` built in to Ubuntu, I set it up via GUI, but on the 19.10 there are some problems with it and I cannot find that damned config file anywhere.

I tried `/etc/openvpn`, `/usr/etc/..`, `/shares..`, `~/.conf`, `....`

`/etc/openvpn/client/...` there are some config files, but they are old and not used anymore, OpenVPN client ignores it anyway.

I am tryin to fix this for a second day in row, I need to do this via terminal, not by GUI.

I need to find the *old* one, not just replace it with the *new* config because of some debugging.

I would *love* `openvpn --get-config-file-path`, but obviously no one *ever* does this when creating some software.

Thanks for some tips on how to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

The `nm-openvpn` package uses NetworkManager to start and stop OpenVPN. The configuration is actually stored in NetworkManager. NetworkManager configuration can be found in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`:

[image]

The idea you suggested; `--get-config-file-path` wouldn't even work here, because NetworkManager doesn't provide a config file to OpenVPN. It uses command-line switches to configure OpenVPN. This is why not all OpenVPN configuration options are available through NetworkManager.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. It did not occur to me, especially the old config file which was used before confused me. You can configure openvpn directly or you can let the NetworkManager handle it.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as answered by using the green checkmark so other people can find it easily (as well as earning me some points ;) ).